# Using full height in nested flex boxes does not work as expected

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/byze7dyy/3/)

```
<div class="content">
    <section class="left">
        <h3>TITLE</h3>
        <div class="image">IMAGE</div>
        <article>TEXT</article>
    </section>
    <section class="right">
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</div>
        <div>Laboriosam, nesciunt itaque aspernatur.</div>
        <div>In quia repellendus nemo!</div>
    </section>
</div>
```

I would like to stretch the section.right elements vertically if there is space left like in this [tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/boxes-fill-height-dont-squish/).
Position absolute is not an option, because if the right content needs more height it should result in growth of section.left also.

I've tried to set section.right to `display: flex`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/byze7dyy/4/)

```
section.right {
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 40%;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

}
```

But it results in colliding the content.
[image: example]

Comment: It's not clear what the issue Is. `display:flex` on the right section seems to do what you want.

Comment: `display:flex` in the right section does partially what i want. If there is not enough height, the content of `section.right > div` collides. see second jsfiddle or screenshot

Comment: Didn't do that in Chrome.

Comment: ok. then ist a safari problem. Do you have an idea, how to solve it cross browser (at least for all current browsers)

Comment: Which version of Safari and have you fully prefixed?

Comment: Version 9.0.1 (10601.2.7.2)

Comment: I thought the prefixes solved it, but it was the `flex: 1 0 auto;` property for `section.right > div`. Anyways, thanks for the help.

Comment: That would make sense because you said you were using Safari 9, which shouldn't need prefixes. That's why I added a source disclaimer in my answer. However, in the comments above it appears the code was working fine in Chrome. Hence the focus on prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

Although Safari 9 supports all standard flex properties ([according to one source](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)), with Safari 8 and older you'll need to use vendor prefixes.

For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, post your CSS in the left panel here: [**Autoprefixer**](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).

For flexbox browser support details see here: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did so.